# where in the official docs the event.on(data) and .on(close) of Response are explained

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know where in the official docs of nodejs, the `Event data` and `Event close` of a `response` are explained. I want to find out where these events are explained so I can learn what other events are available to be used.

I was checking these official docs [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/http.html) but I could not find any explanation and could not find what are other event are available to be fired on `response` object

**my code:**

```
var options = {
    protocol:'https:',
    host: constants.END_POINT_HOST_JK,
    path: constants.END_POINT_PATH_JK,
    method:'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
};
  
var callback = (response)=>{
    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.error("Did not get an OK from the server. Code:",response.statusCode);
        console.error("Did not get an OK from the server. Msg:",response.statusMessage);
        res.resume();
        return;
      }
    var data = '';
    response.on('data', (chunk)=>{
        data += chunk;
    });

    response.on('close', ()=>{
        console.log('Retrieved all data');
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
}

var req=https.request(options, callback);
req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error("problem with request:", e);
});
req.end();
```

Comment: @PierreD yes. but data and close are not there..aren't they?

Comment: there is no definite list. The closest you can get is a list of the officially implanted events in Node. (see my answer)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the link directly to the page you asked for:

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#eventsonemitter-eventname-options

*how to get to it

So in the node docs, scroll down on the left menu, until you get to events:
https://nodejs.org/api/events.html and then there is `events.on()` in there.

Your link was to the `http` section of the nodejs docs. Try using the left menu thing to access different aspects of node.

EDIT:
My above answer does not answer the whole scope of this question, as mentioned by @Quentin.

I did a bit more research on this.

Using the EventEmitter class of node.js events, you can create **custom** events to that can be fired, and handled by the `events.on()` function. Here is an example:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

// Create a new instance of EventEmitter
const emitter = new EventEmitter();

// Register an event handler for 'myEvent'
emitter.on('myEvent', (arg1, arg2) => {
  console.log('myEvent occurred with arguments:', arg1, arg2);
});

// Emit the 'myEvent' event
emitter.emit('myEvent', 'Hello', 'World');
```

Therefore, there is no **definitive** list of events that can be constructed.

In node.js, there is, however, a predefined list of events that can be caught by the `events.on()` function, and can always be emmited. The list is numerous and hard to compile (I can't find it anywhere either)
Here is a condensed version consisting of the more commonly used:

### EventEmitter (events module)

`newListener`: Emitted when a new listener is added.

`removeListener`: Emitted when a listener is removed.

### HTTP module

`request`: Emitted when an HTTP request is received.

`response`: Emitted when an HTTP response is sent.

`close`: Emitted when the server closes.

### Stream module

`data`: Emitted when data is available to read from a readable stream.

`end`: Emitted when there is no more data to be consumed from a readable stream.

`finish`: Emitted when all data has been flushed to a writable stream.

### File System (fs module)

`open`: Emitted when a file is opened.

`close`: Emitted when a file is closed.

### Child Process module

`exit`: Emitted when a child process exits.

### Net module

`connect`: Emitted when a socket connection is successfully established.

`data`: Emitted when data is received on a socket.

`end`: Emitted when the other end of the socket sends a FIN packet.

### Timer functions (setTimeout, setInterval)

`timeout`: Emitted when a timer function completes.

### DNS module

`lookup`: Emitted when a DNS lookup is completed.

### Process

`exit`: Emitted when the Node.js process is about to exit.

`uncaughtException`: Emitted when an unhandled exception occurs.

`warning`: Emitted when a warning is issued.

### Readline module

`line`: Emitted when the line event is triggered by the readline.Interface instance.

`close`: Emitted when the close event is triggered by the readline.Interface instance.

### HTTP Server

`checkContinue`: Emitted when the server receives a request with the expect: 100-continue header.

`clientError`: Emitted when a client connection emits an error.

### HTTP Client (http.request)

`socket`: Emitted when a socket is assigned to the request.

`abort`: Emitted when the request is aborted.

### Stream

`error`: Emitted when an error occurs in a stream.

### Child Process (child_process.spawn, child_process.fork)

`message`: Emitted when a child process sends a message using process.send().

### DNS Resolver (dns.resolve, dns.lookup)

`error`: Emitted when an error occurs during DNS resolution.

### EventEmitter

`error`: Emitted when an error occurs within an EventEmitter instance.

## close and data

in the question, you asked about data and close.

Data:

The .on('data', callback) event handler is commonly used with readable streams in Node.js. It is used to handle the 'data' event, which is emitted when data is available to be read from the stream. This event is typically used to consume the data being read from the stream and process it in some way. The callback function passed to .on('data', callback) is invoked with the data as the argument each time the 'data' event is emitted.

Here's an example that demonstrates the usage of the 'data' event handler with a readable stream:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Create a readable stream
const readableStream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt');

// Handle the 'data' event
readableStream.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('Data received:', data);
});
```

whenever data is available to be read from the 'file.txt' file, the 'data' event is emitted by the readable stream

close:

the .on('close', callback) event handler, it is commonly used to handle the 'close' event, which is emitted when a resource, such as a stream or a socket, is closed. The 'close' event can indicate that the resource has been successfully closed or that an error occurred during the closing process.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Create a writable stream
const writableStream = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt');

// Handle the 'close' event
writableStream.on('close', () => {
  console.log('Stream closed');
});

// Close the writable stream
writableStream.end();
```

after calling writableStream.end(), which finishes writing data to the stream and closes it, the 'close' event is emitted. The provided callback function is executed.

Note: I realize that this is not exactly what you were asking for, as you wanted the info in the Node.js docs, but I believe that they are not too clear about certain points, and that I did a decent job explaining the events, and @Quentin did a good job with the links to the documentation.

Comment: That describes the on method, not the events that you can use on to listen for on an http response.

Answer (score -2):

You are *starting* at the [right place](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/http.html).

Scroll down to http.IncomingMessage

See that it Extends: stream.Readable

[Click that](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable).

The events you are asking about aren’t unique to HTTP responses, so they are inherited from the parent class and the documentation is linked not duplicated.

Comment: That is a **usage** of the events.on(), not the docs about it.

Comment: @Hermanboxcar — following those instructions takes me to a list of the events in readable streams, with descriptions of them, including the ones names by the OP. It’s exactly what they are asking for.

Comment: it takes me to functions like readable.read() where it is only used in the docs of another function. The use of the `events.on` function is not limited to the HTTP module.

Comment: @Hermanboxcar — It takes me here: https://imgur.com/a/9Dh3XbZ which is the description of the events the OP is asking about.

Comment: Oh I did not see that

Comment: Sorry, I think there is like issue of the scroll on my device so the link that you provided makes me scroll to almost the end of the page. Also, under streamWritable on the same page, https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/stream.html#class-streamwritable , it also mentions close and data.